# Stripe payment service not Emailed customer automatically with created invoice using it's API

Tags: stripe-payments

I create invoice using stripe API (Java) and add argument billing as 'Send_invoice' and the invoice created fine, as documentation says this will email the customer with payment instructions but this not happen (the customer not Emailed automatically by created invoice), the invoice only sent to customer in case when manually click on send button of the invoice. this scenario happens in Test and Live mode, So please I don't understand what makes the customer not Emailed automatically when the invoice is created.

Answer (score 11):

This is expected: Stripe does not automatically send emails in test mode. You can trigger the emails manually via the dashboard.

In live mode, the invoice would be automatically emailed to the customer as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm With you, the customer emailed by the invoice at live mode, but my case is I create the invoice using API with needed arguments at live mode and it created fine but the customer not emailed automatically with that invoice.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I read your question a bit too fast and thought this was only happening in test mode. What value are you providing for `days_until_due`?

Comment: Never mind, I used "due_date"  as timeStamp and test scenario before and after due date, according to the documentation it says when the argument billing is 'Send_invoice' this will email customer by invoice, but this not happen.